# Fundamental group of the quotient of $\partial I$ with a simply connected space

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was wondering under what conditions will the quotient of I at its endpoints $\partial I$ with a simply connected space will give $\pi_1 = \mathbb{Z}$.  To be clear, the end points do not need to quotient to the same point.  I think I have a proof for $T_1$ spaces, and I'm having trouble of thinking up counter examples for non-$T_1$.  Is there a standard proof for all spaces?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think a clearer phrasing of the operation you're asking about would be "*gluing* the endpoints of an interval to a simply connected space", or to be categorical about it, taking the [pushout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)) of the inclusion $\partial I\hookrightarrow I$ with a map $\partial I\to X$ where $X$ is simply connected